# Unable to set header in Linear layout in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00b9e8"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            android:text="Serch"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/backbutton" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#6AED83"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Footer"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
        android:text="Enter Mobile Number"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedlinearlayout3"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/user_s_icon" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Mobile Number"
            android:textColorHint="#0060a4" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signin"
        android:layout_width="244dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10pt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my Xml i am Unable to set Linear layout inside text view and image button Like desire image:[image]

This is my desire screen :  below is my current screen :[image]

[image]

i am unable to set text-view and image view on top of Linear layout

Comment: Your in a `RelativeLayout` and it doesn't look like you're giving any "relative" layout conditions.  Might want to start with the [Documentation Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Comment: i have to add header in given Screen  please see my current screen and given screeen

Comment: I understand.  That guide will show you how to use `RelativeLayout` (and `LinearLayout` if you want to look there).  It really is best to understand the basics of the tools you're working with, so I tried to help.

Comment: i am unable to set header in left full and right  we have to use Linear lay Out for that?

Comment: No, either will work.  Please read up on them so that you know how to get the most from the tools you have.  I'm willing to bet you'll say to yourself, "How silly that I did not read the guides first?!" :)

Comment: am unable to set right and left and top full like desire screen please tell me The Solution i have even use include also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Instead of using RelativeLayout use LinearLayout which can be easily done your requirement.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00b9e8"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Serch"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/backbutton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter Mobile Number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedlinearlayout3">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Mobile Number"
                android:textColorHint="#0060a4"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_s_icon">
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signin"
            android:layout_width="244dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="10pt" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#6AED83"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Footer"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanx 
Haresh Chhelana

Comment: can i have ur Skype id i have some small small 2 query to ask

Comment: no you can ask me on mail which mention in my profile and can you please upvote if ans is useful to you...

Comment: tell ur email id please

Comment: wait i am sending one mail please just guive XML for that color and icon i ll change u put any default